# How do I prevent a jQuery extend deep copy from copying some of my custom properties?

Tags: javascript, jquery, extend

I have some custom properties on some of my objects, which I would like to keep unique per object.

Some third party code, however, is attempting to use jQuery to .extend some of my objects - with the deep-copy flag turned on.

I would like to prevent these properties from being deep copied. My intuition is to overwrite the jQuery.extend (and jQuery.fn.extend) functions, with functions which ignore my properties, but that sounds like overkill.

Comment: How come some third-party code modifies your own objects? And how does that interfere with your own code?

Comment: You don't have a lot of options besides removing some of the custom properties until after the copy is performed.

Comment: Just what i was wondering. Are you getting cross site scripting attacks?

Comment: There are all sorts of cool libraries that tend do this sort of thing - debugging and testing frameworks are probably the ones most people are familiar with.

Comment: pretty sure .Clone() does not deep copy. Maybe you can clone your object which the third party is trying to extend ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties added through

```
Object.defineProperty
```

with the enumerable argument set to false won't be caught by jQuery.extend.

---

```
a = { b: 'b'};
Object.defineProperty(a,'bb',{ get: function() {return "bb";},enumerable: false});
c = {};
jQuery.extend(c,a,a,a,a);
a.b  // "b"
a.bb // "bb"
c.b  // "b"
c.bb // undefined
```